# Wordpress drop down page in post/page select

Tags: wordpress

Is there any code or plugin for Wordpress drop down page in post/page select
That looks like here http://www.hardocp.com/article/2013/06/24/asus_z87deluxe_lga_1150_motherboard_review#.Uclv3pyrF0U

From my comments

Thx for code where to i put this code and in which file. Is this plugin helphful http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/drop-down-post-list-plugin-for-wordpress/ ?

I downloaded Insert PHP plugin and put code in post and didn't worked Then i put this code to template and is buged. Option select don't work it only show all pages name I meant to be post next page like entering `<!--nextpage-->` (Wordpress code for nextpage) into post and it could give page(new page) a new name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go place the code in your file

```
<?php 
$pages = get_pages(); 
 ?>
<select onchange="window.location=this.value" >
<?php 
foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
//$content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content); 
//$title = $page_data->post_title;
?> 

<option value="<?php  echo get_page_link($page_data->ID);?>"><?php echo $page_data->post_title;?></option>

<?php } ?>
 </select>
```

Hope it works fine

Comment: Thx for code where to i put this code and in which file.
Is this plugin helphful http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/drop-down-post-list-plugin-for-wordpress/ ?

Comment: I downloaded Insert PHP plugin and put code in post and didn't worked
Then i put this code to template and is buged.

Option select don't work it only show all pages name

I meant to be post next page like entering <!--nextpage--> into post and it could give page(new page) a new name

Comment: sorry i didn't get you second point for first point put this code in the `header.php` of your theme after the `<body>` tag can you explain your second concern

Comment: How to get this code work for page of page when i add nextpage code that pages disapepear
This is from cource code when code from dianuj wasn't used
`<div class="page-links">
      Pages: 1 
    <a href="http://www.hotelpedia.si/stran/nextpage/2/">
      2
    </a>`